# This if statement is being 'marked' as false even though the conditions in the if statement is true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this very weird problem with this if statement. This code here

```
    Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y);
    if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 20 && x >= -2)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, -20, 0);
        coolDown = true;
    }
```

does not work. It says the euler angle of y is 20, but for some reason, the if statement is not being checked as true. I tried taking out the euler angle in that if statement and it was checked as true, meaning that the euler angle for some reason is not 20, even though it is printing out as 20. And another weird thing is that this code here

```
    if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 340 && x <= -11)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 20, 0);
        coolDown = true;

    }
```

works. It is the exact same code and I don't know why the first code worked and this second one did not. What is wrong with the code?

(x is a variable for gameObject.transform.position.x btw)

here is the whole code (kinda messy cuz I'm not that good at coding yet ;-;)

```
public float horizontalInput;
public int horizontalInput2;
public float Speed;
public float TimeSpeed;
public bool TimeSpeed2;
public float TimeSpeed3;
public float x;
public int yValue = 20;
public bool coolDown = true;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (gameObject.transform.position.x <= -11)
    {

    }
    TimeSpeed3++;
    if (TimeSpeed3 == 75)
    {
        TimeSpeed2 = true;
        TimeSpeed3 = 0;
    }
    if (TimeSpeed == 100)
    {
        TimeSpeed2 = true;
    }
    if (TimeSpeed == 30)
    {

        Speed++;
        TimeSpeed = 0;
        if (Speed > 60)
        {
            float v = Speed - 0.8f;
            Speed = v;
            if (Speed > 100)
            {
                v = Speed - 0.18f;
                Speed = v;
            }
            if (Speed >= 105)
            {
                v = Speed - 0.2f;
                Speed = v;
            }
        }
    }
    

    x = gameObject.transform.position.x;
    TimeSpeed++;
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && coolDown == true)
    {
        if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            horizontalInput2 = -1;
        }
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 20 * horizontalInput2);
        if (x <= -11)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        }
        Debug.Log(coolDown);
        coolDown = false;
    }
    if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 340 && x <= -11)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 20, 0);
        coolDown = true;

    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && coolDown == true)
    {
        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            horizontalInput2 = 1;
        }
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 20 * horizontalInput2);
        coolDown = false;
    }
    Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y);
    if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 20 && x >= -2)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, -20, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `x` is not `gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.x`

Comment: yeah ik x is a variable for transform.position.x

Comment: Could the y data be a decimal?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, because `x` is not the same as `transform.position.x`, either.

Comment: no the y printed out to be a flat number with no decimals ( a 20)

Comment: wait wdym madreflection?

Comment: You said that "x is a variable for transform.position.x" but until you show what that means, that could be interpreted in multiple ways. Don't describe it. Show the code.

Comment: is `eulerAngles.y` a `double` (or any other floating point type). If yes can you try `if (Math.abs(20 -gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y) < 0.0001 && ...)`

Comment: Okay, this is another point about specificity: you said that "x is a variable for transform.position.x", but you omitted the `gameObject.` part. That matters. Don't take shortcuts when explaining things. It only works against you.

Comment: wait that worked........... derpirscher

Comment: that must have been the case....

Comment: that is so weird tho bc in the console, it just printed 20 with no decimals....

Comment: @Idkv.2 float's ToString() method (which is called by Unity's Log) only includes precision up to 7 digits.  If you have a number like 20.000001, it's just going to print "20" even though it isn't exactly 20

Comment: huh. I'll have to remember that in the future then